# Behaviour of the solution of a second order ODE

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, graphing-functions

I am currently studying the following second order ODE
\begin{cases}
\ddot y(x)\left(\ln(x) - 2\ln(y(x))\right) - 2\frac{(\dot y(x))^2}{y(x)} = 0 &\text{in }[0,T]\\
y(0) = 0\\
\dot y(T) = c
\end{cases}
for $c$ a positive constant and $T > 0$ and arbitrarily small constant. Clearly, solving this ODE explicitly is not doable. But actually for my purpose I don't need a whole solution but rather to understand the behaviour of $\dot y(x)$ near $0$. I would like to know if $\lim_{x \to 0} \dot y(x) = 0 $ or not.

Being not really familiar with the tools used in ODE theory, I was wondering if one of you guide me on this topic. I solved the ODE numerically using *Maple* and the software gave me the following plots[image]

where I fixed $T = 1/2$ and the initial conditions set at $c = 1, 1/2$ and $1/3$ corresponding to $1, 2$ and $3$ respectively. It seems that the slope at the origin is always strictly positive, whatever initial condition I set (if I decrease $c$ or $T$, the behaviour remains the same). However, I have absolutely no idea how to do that. Any help?

Comment: For what it's worth: Your ODE is generalized homogeneous. Let $y=x^{1/2}\xi(t)$, $\log(x)=t$ to bring to an autonomous equation. Then let $\xi'_t=-u(\xi)/\log(\xi)$ to get the first order Abel equation 
\begin{align}
uu'_\xi-u=\frac\xi4\left(1-\frac{1}{\log(\xi)}\right).
\end{align}

Comment: I am unsure how you make it autonomous. I agree that you make the $x$ disappear in the term $(\ln(x) - 2\ln(y))$ but, if my computation are correct, the term $(\dot y)^2/y$ leads to 
$$\frac{(\dot y)^2}{y} = \frac{1}{4} \frac{\left(\ln \xi + 4 \dot \xi/ \xi\right)^2}{t + \ln \xi},$$
and the $t$ still appears in the equation.

Comment: Note that $\mathrm d_x=1/x \mathrm d_t$, so $\xi’_x=\xi’_t/x$.
\begin{align}
y’=x^{-1/2}(\xi_t’+\xi/2),\quad y’’=x^{-3/2}(\xi_{tt}’’-\xi/4),\\
\log\left(\frac{x}{(x^{1/2}\xi)^2}\right)x^{-3/2}(\xi_{tt}’’-\xi/4)=2\frac{(x^{-1/2}(\xi_t’+\xi/2))^2}{x^{1/2}\xi}\\
-2\log(\xi)x^{-3/2}(\xi’’_{tt}-\xi/4)=2\frac{x^{-1}}{x^{1/2}}\frac{(\xi’_t+\xi/2)^2}{\xi}\\
\xi\log(\xi)(\xi’’_{tt}-\xi/4)+(\xi_t’+\xi/2)^2=0.
\end{align}

Comment: Note that if $y$ is real, then it cannot be negative, as $\ln(y)$ would be complex. So we have $y(x) \geq 0$ $\forall x \in [0, T]$. Then, the initial condition $y(0) = 0$ leads to $\dot{y}(0) \geq 0$, otherwise $y(0^+)$ is negative.

Comment: @Eli Bartlett yes I did a stupid mistake my bad.